# Security issue , Session high jacking prevention

Tags: php, session, session-cookies

Here is the problem.. ( using yii 1.1 framework )

1. I loggedin by user id 100 in chrome browser
2. After logging just copy sesion value from chrome browser and paste this value in mozilla browser and refresh the page and user 100 is logged in.
3. The user is logged in by this procedure.

Methods apply to this situation are..
1. Session id generated after every login.
2. Token store and validate on every action
3. Machin ip +user id + token hash with every action in before action and validate in controller.php in before action
4. Creat open ssl ( slft singn certificate ).

No method is work for me. 
Please suggest me best way to resolve this problem.